# In Influxdb, how do I concat values in my query?

Tags: influxdb

I would like to query all rows where columnA = 'xyz' + columnB:

```
select * from myTable where colA = 'xyz' + colB
```

Comment: So what have you tried? What error message did you get? There's nothing wrong with your query from what I can see.

Comment: Please provide more detail what types (tag, filed) are colB and colA. More details would help show how this is done.